Bootstrap selectpicker icon to change dynamically
I successfully changed the icon of boostrap selectpicker in the css file using:
.status.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle::after {
  border: none;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1;
  font-style: bold;
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
  content: "\F22C"; /* the desired FontAwesome icon */
  vertical-align: 0; /* to center vertically */
}

But I wanted to change the icon dynamically using jquery.
The logic/sequence is that after the user selected an option, the icon will change.
From '\F22C' as default to '\F3E0' (when the user selected in the option)
This is what I have tried in jquery:
$('#input-status-select').change(function() {

    if($('#input-status-select :selected').length > 0) {
        $("<style>.status.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle::after { border: none!important; font: normal normal normal 14px/1; font-family: 'bootstrap-icons'; content: '\F3E0' !important; vertical-align: 0;} </style>").appendTo("head");
    }
    else {
        $("<style>.status.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle::after { border: none!important; font: normal normal normal 14px/1; font-family: 'bootstrap-icons'; content: '\F22C'!important; vertical-align: 0;} </style>").appendTo("head");
    }
    filter_data();
});


What's happening is that the icon is changing, but it displays 'F3E0' literally instead of icon.
What am I missing?
Do I need to have to whitelist or something?
This is the sample html code:
 <select data-selected-text-format="static" title="Choose Option" class="status selectpicker form-control" data-size = "6" data-live-search = "true" style="width: 15%;"
multiple id="input-status-select" data-actions-box="true" aria-label="size 3 select example">
   <option name='checkbox_status[]' value='1' class='common_selector status' 
      common_selector status>Sample 1</option>
   <option name='checkbox_status[]'  value='2' class='common_selector status' 
      common_selector status>Sample 2</option>
</select>


Attached picture is what's being display when I chose an option.

You should rather not be creating a new style element every time the selection changes, to begin with. Do this by adding/removing a class on the element - and then put a corresponding rule into your stylesheet, that applies the other icon.

@C3roe that is indeed the best option to do in all of these kinds of situations

I have tried adding/removing class on the element, and put corresponding rule in the stylesheet. It works now :) Thank you so much for the suggestion
